# libGDX's Collision is not working properly in my update method

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a project in android studio for libGDX. I used this collision system in my player class and it worked! But when I check in my Bullet class it doesn't work and gives me an error!

('em' is an entity manager btw)
(em.entities is an Array which is libgdx's version of an ArrayList)

```
for (Entity e : em.entities) {
    if (e instanceof Enemy) {
        if (getBounds().contains(e.getBounds())) {
            System.out.println("Collided!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"       com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used
>   nested.
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array$ArrayIterator.hasNext(Array.java:550)
>       at com.thechief.game.entities.EntityManager.update(EntityManager.java:35)
>       at com.thechief.game.screen.GameScreen.update(GameScreen.java:29)
>       at com.thechief.game.Main.render(Main.java:50)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
>       at     com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the iterator, as that is not allowed for nested loops. Just use a traditional for loop instead of an iterator.

```
for(int i=0;i<em.entities.size;i++){
    Entity e=em.engities.get(i);
    if (e instanceof Enemy) {
         if (getBounds().contains(e.getBounds())) {
                System.out.println("Collided!");
         }
    }
}
```